# How to fix error "ValueError: <Follower: Follower object (None)> instance is not saved." Use bulk = False or save the object first. "

Tags: python, django, github

I wanted to create a follower system, and I get a "ValueError:  instance is not saved." Use bulk = False or save the object first. " .Please how to solve this problem, sorry for my bad writing!!

```
#my models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class Follower(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='following', on_delete=None)
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='followers', on_delete=None)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('follower', 'following')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s follows %s' % (self.follower, self.following)

#in the interpreter
>>> from followers.models import *

>>> john = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'password')
>>> paul = User.objects.create_user('paul', 'mccartney@thebeatles.com', 'password')
>>> george = User.objects.create_user('george', 'harrison@thebeatles.com', 'password')
>>> ringo = User.objects.create_user('ringo', 'starr@thebeatles.com', 'password')

#the mistake comes from here
>>> john.following.add(Follower(following=paul))
```

and I get

in add "the object first." % obj
ValueError:  instance isn't saved. Use bulk=False or save the object first.`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `Follower` object like:

```
Follower.objects.create(follower=john, following=paul)
```

You can *not* add *unsaved* objects to a *one-to-many* or *many-to-many* relation, since at that moment they do not have a primary key yet. Since here your `ForeignKey`s are non-nullable, you can not first save the `Follower` object with one of the two relations filled in, and then use `.add(..)` to add the other end, but that would be more expensive anyway, since it results in two queries.

You can also make `Follower` objects in bulk like:

```
Follower.objects.bulk_create([
    Follower(follower=john, following=paul),
    Follower(follower=john, following=ringo),
    Follower(follower=ringo, following=paul),
    Follower(follower=george, following=ringo)
])
```

Comment: @LEVIKEHA: the above was constructed in 2014. Which was an older version of both Python (2.7) and Django (1.8 iirc).